# what is the better way read a Block of SQL statements from a file using Shell Script?

Tags: awk, sed, sql-parser

I am having a file like below , which has many SQL statements. I want to read a particular block of SQL whenever needed.

MyFile.SQL

```
#QUERY1
SET ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET NUMFORMAT 99999999999999999
Select max(time_created) from test.table1 where cust=1;
EXIT;

#QUERY2
SET ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET NUMFORMAT 99999999999999999
Select count(*) from test.table1 where cust=1;
EXIT;


#QUERY3
SET ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET NUMFORMAT 99999999999999999
Select count(*) from test.table12 where acct=1;

EXIT;
```

I am using below command

```
x=$(cat test.sql )
echo $x | awk -F'COUNT_QUERY' '{ print $0 }'
```

Could someone help with some good approach to this?

Comment: Could you please do add sample of expected output into your post and let us know and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : If I want to extract only QUERY2 then My expected output should be #QUERY2
SET ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET NUMFORMAT 99999999999999999
Select count(*) from test.table1 where cust=1;
EXIT;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^#QUERY2$/{found=1} found; /^EXIT/ && found{exit}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                 ##Starting awk program from here.
/^#QUERY2/{           ##Checking condition if line starts with #QUERY2 then do following.
  found=1             ##Setting found value as 1 here.
}
found;                ##Checking condition if found is SET then print that line.
/^EXIT/ && found{     ##Checking condition if line starts with EXIT and found is SET then do following.
  exit                ##exit from program from here.
}
'  Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @1stenjoydmoment, it check if line has `#QUERY2` then printing it from that line to `EXIT` so is string query2 present in your file?

Comment: Yes. Its working. Thanks for the pointer. My bad I ran with another file. can please provide link for this documentation "shown samples in GNU awk" for my understanding

Comment: @1stenjoydmoment, I have added detailed explanation for above and for learning awk you could use https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info which has great learning info in it cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Data like yours where records are separated by blank lines is why awk has a "paragraph mode" that's activated by setting RS to null:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/^#QUERY2\n/' file
#QUERY2
SET ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET NUMFORMAT 99999999999999999
Select count(*) from test.table1 where cust=1;
EXIT;
```

See `When RS is set to the empty string ...` in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line for more info.